# How to find position of two endpoints given a distance to travel?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Let's say I walking on the number line starting from 0 to 5. When I reach 5, If there still distance I need to travel, I go the reverse direction, walking from 5 to 0.
Examples:

- Given 3 units of distance, I reach 3.
- Given 5 units of distance, I reach 5.
- Given 6 units of distance, I reach 4.
- Given 8 units of distance, I reach 2.
- Given 10 units of distance, I reach 0.

In general, given two points, a and b, and a < b, on the number line and distance D to travel, how do I find the position of the person when D == 0.

The expression I came up with is 
final_pos = start_pos + distance mod (end_pos - start_pos). which fails when it does the returning.

Comment: I like to know where the person ends up given some distance D to travel in a range [a, b], where a < b. The person goes back and forth until D == 0. Hopefully this clarifies my question. I know I'm bad at wording

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end position depends on the evenness of the `quotient` when `distance` is divided by `b-a`. If it is even  then the end position is `a+r` where `r` is the remainder when `distance` divided by `b-a`. Otherwise, the end position is `b-r`.

```
using static System.Console;


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 3;
        int distance = 7;

        int quotient = distance / (b - a);
        int remainder = distance % (b - a);
        if (quotient % 2 == 0)
            WriteLine($"end position: {a + remainder }");
        else
            WriteLine($"end position: {b - remainder }");

    }
}
```

## Edit

Or you can represent as follows:

$$
\text{end position} = \frac{(a+r)\left(1+(-1)^q\right)+(b-r)\left(1-(-1)^q\right)}{2}
$$

where $r$ is the remainder and $q$ is the quotient.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Of course you can use trigonometry as well.